# Wi-Fi profile installation became slow in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, wifi, configuration-profile

I am having an issue with the installation of WiFi configuration profiles after updating to iOS8.

With iOS7 the installation of a WiFi profile (with 20 WiFi networks) just takes 2 or 3 seconds, but using iOS8 the installation of the same WiFi profile can take up to an hour! During this time the iPhone becomes slow and the user is not able to enter into the WiFi settings of the phone.

I have tried the installation of the same WiFi profile in different scenarios:

- iPhone 4 / 4S with iOS 7: Takes 2 or 3 seconds
- iPhone 5 / 5S with iOS 7: Takes 2 or 3 seconds
- iPhone 5 / 5S with iOS8 (8.0/8.1/8.2): Takes up to an hour
- iPhone 6 with iOS8: Takes up to an hour
- iPhone 6 plus with iOS8: Takes 5 seconds aprox.
- iPad Air 2 with iOS 8: Takes 5 seconds aprox.
- iPad Mini with iOS 8: Takes up to 3 mins.

Also tried with the profile signed by Thawte using openssl_pkcs7_sign and not signed with the same result.
This is the XML aspect of the profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>PayloadContent</key>
      <array>
         <dict>
            <key>AutoJoin</key>
            <true />
            <key>EncryptionType</key>
            <string>WPA</string>
            <key>HIDDEN_NETWORK</key>
            <false />
            <key>Password</key>
            <string>XXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configura los ajustes de conectividad inalÃ¡mbrica.</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Wi-Fi XXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string>XXXXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.wifi.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>XXXXXXXX</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ProxyType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>SSID_STR</key>
            <string>SSIDXXXX</string>
         </dict>
      </array>
      <key>PayloadDescription</key>
      <string>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX</string>
      <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
      <string>XXXXXXX Wi-Fis</string>
      <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
      <string>com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx</string>
      <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
      <string>XXXXXXXX</string>
      <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
      <false />
      <key>PayloadType</key>
      <string>Configuration</string>
      <key>PayloadUUID</key>
      <string>XXXXXXXXXX</string>
      <key>PayloadVersion</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>DurationUntilRemoval</key>
      <integer>2592000</integer>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

https://gist.github.com/medaqueno/b2927082a3662fe2d472

What´s wrong with my xml file? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be something worthwhile to bug report to Apple as I don't see anything initially wrong with it and it appears to be a regression starting from iOS 8.  Be sure to include a version of the profile you're using when you report it as they'll need to reproduce the stall you're seeing with the older hardware.  Also, OpenRadar if you can (http://openradar.appspot.com/faq).

Comment: Thanks for your indications. I have reported a bug to Apple and now I have just included it in OpenRadar. I will notify any update in order to help others with the same issue.